# facebook app reloading in loop, login logout events getting fired automatically inside window.fbAsyncInit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a facebook (iframe) app.

I have included following code at bottom of my page:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();  

        FB.init({
            appId   : '<?php echo FACEBOOK_APP_ID; ?>',
            session : '<?php echo json_encode($session); ?>',
            status  : true,
            cookie  : true,
            xfbml   : true
        });

        // whenever the user logs in / out, we refresh the page
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {               
            window.location.reload();               
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function() {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    };

    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());

</script>
```

The problem here is, it seems that auth.login and auth.logout events are getting fired immediately inside window.fbAsyncInit function, even if I do not log-out from (or log-in to if logged out) my facebook profile.

I am doing no such action, even then these events seem to get fired, which causes their handler functions to reload my app (window.location.reload();), and the app goes into infinite reload loop.

Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From my experience instead of using auth.logout and auth.login events you may try the following code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // the user is logged in and connected to your
      // app, and response.authResponse supplies
      // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
      // request, and the time the access token 
      // and signed request each expire
      var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
      var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
      //but not connected to the app
    } else {
      // the user isn't even logged in to Facebook.
    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been stuck trying to solve this bug for a few days. The thing is that auth.login event is fired when the SDK is loaded even if you're already connected thus creating an infinite loop. I've solved it when i made the code listen to the authlogin event and reloading the page only if the user is not connected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo AppInfo::appID(); ?>', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true // parse XFBML
    });

    // Listen to the auth.login which will be called when the user logs in
    // using the Login button
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        console.log (response.status);
        //this is useful if you want to avoid the infinite loop bug
        //it only reloads page when you log in
        if (response.status != 'connected') {
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                // We want to reload the page now so PHP can read the cookie that the
                // Javascript SDK sat. But we don't want to use
                // window.location.reload() because if this is in a canvas there was a
                // post made to this page and a reload will trigger a message to the
                // user asking if they want to send data again.
                //window.location = window.location;
                //Im using the window.location.reload()
                window.location.reload();
            });
        }
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

Hope this works!

Anyway this is not the only problem i have. please check this post and help me if you can
[impossible to read $_SESSION vars on PHP facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910009/impossible-to-read-session-vars-on-php-facebook-app)